# OpenWeatherMap api is not returning associative array for errors

Tags: php, openweathermap

I'm using OpenWeatherMap API and the API is working completely fine when I passed the valid city and API key but let's say someone entered the wrong city or API, it would return the following errors 401 and 404

but instead of returning those errors in an associative array (json_decode), it is returning this error

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

I'm trying to get those errors in an associative array format for validation

```
    $weather_api = file_get_contents("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}");
    $weather_data = json_decode($weather_api, true);
      
    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($weather_data);
    echo "</pre>";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.ignore-errors

Comment: Got it! The problem has been resolved! Thank you